# PopUp screen not opening In webview?

Tags: android, webview, popup

I am Currently working with webview in which Javascript popup is created when some button is clicked in webview. But it is not opening in my Webview.

My code is Here:

```
wvPayements = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.wvPaymentsPage);
    wvPayements.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    wvPayements.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    wvPayements.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    wvPayements.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    wvPayements.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wvPayements.getSettings()
            .setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    wvPayements.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    wvPayements.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, final String url) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
     wvPayements
     .loadUrl("http://192.168.0.114/Parch_ws/testalert.html");
```

Comment: i didn't see any dialog being popped up here

Comment: its coming from web..not android native..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to use WebChromeClient for your purpose:

> One should use a WebChromeClient to get these alerts and the
> functionality can be overwritten using the`onJsAlert()` method. Hope
> this helps!
>
> ```
> WebView wv=new WebView(this); 
> wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
>     @Override
>     public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, JsResult result) {
>         //Required functionality here
>         return super.onJsAlert(view, url, message, result);
>     }
> });
> ```

Source: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36905249#comment11

Comment: Thnx buddy..you saved my hours.

Comment: Hello @Hardik, I used this method but this is not working in my case. Is there any other setting need to do?

Comment: @SwapnilSonar you have to do using web chrome client.

Comment: Actually we are working on web application in which we facilitating to user to login in app with `Linkedin`, it is fantastically work in web and android browser. But when we try to access it in android webview linkedin login popup/dialog is not open up.

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if you are executing ES6 on unsupported browsers.

You can always check supported versions [here](https://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions)